# Providing credentials for Microsoft Report Server when using a WebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, authentication, webrequest, reportserver

I would like to download a PDF report from our Microsoft Report Server using my C# code. I don't know why, but I' m doing something wrong. I always get an error back that the authentication failed (HTTP 401).

```cs
public static async Task<Stream> DownloadWebDocument(string url) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url));

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

    request.Method = "GET";
    request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MyUsername", "MyPassword", "MyDomain");

    //request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Basic {Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("MyUsername:MyPassword"))}");

    try {
        using WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();

        return response.GetResponseStream();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        var a = ex.Message;

        throw;
    }

    //return await DownloadWebDocument(uri);
}
```

This code always runs into the exception. But why?

**PS:**

As requested, here's the stack trace. There is no inner exception.

```
   bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   bei System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   bei DE.ZA.TrailerLoadingAssistant.Web.Code.WebHelper.<DownloadWebDocument>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Reichelt\source\repos\DE.ZA.TrailerLoading\DE.ZA.TrailerLoadingAssistant.Web\Code\WebHelper.cs:Zeile 28.
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the exception thrown? Stack trace, inner exceptions, 
 error codes, response body?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen No inner exception. I'll add the stack trace above.

Comment: And the exception type + message?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen It's a `WebException`. The message is "Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (401) Nicht autorisiert." The status field is set to `ProtocolError`.

Comment: I realized, that if I use `request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`, it works. So there must be something wrong with my credentials. But it's definitely no typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realized, that if I use request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials, it works. So there must be something wrong with my credentials. But it's definitely no typo.

I've had this problem and it seemed someone was changing the network permissions. One week using Credentials would work then the next week using DefaultCredentials worked. Really strange, so I put in a Try/Catch and resort to the DefaultCredentials if the Service Account fails, see the code comment:

```
public class SRSHelper
{
    private ReportingService2005 rsServ;
    private ReportingExecution2005 rsExec = new ReportingExecution2005();
    private ReportParameter[] reportParameters;
    private ExecutionInfo execInfo = null;

    public SRSHelper(string reportUserName, string decryptedPassword, string reportDomain, string reportServerURL)
     {
        rsServ = new ReportingService2005(reportServerURL);
        rsExec.Url = reportServerURL + @"ReportExecution2005.asmx";

        System.Net.NetworkCredential creds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        creds.UserName = reportUserName;
        creds.Password = decryptedPassword;
        creds.Domain = reportDomain;
        rsExec.Credentials = creds;
        rsServ.Credentials = creds;
     }

    public ReportParameter[] GetSRSReportParameters(string reportName)
    {
        string report = "/Reporting/" + reportName;
        bool forRendering = false;
        string historyID = null;
        ParameterValue[] values = null;
        DataSourceCredentials[] credentials = null;

        try
        {
            return rsServ.GetReportParameters(report, historyID, forRendering, values, credentials);
        }
        catch
        {
            //If the Service Account credentials fail to work - try the users credentials - XYZ vendor regularly change things around or the network fails or for some reason beyond our control we have to change the settings.
            rsExec.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            rsServ.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            return rsServ.GetReportParameters(report, historyID, forRendering, values, credentials);
        }
            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I use different method to render my report as PDF document:

```
    public static byte[] DownloadAsPDF(string ReportServer, string ReportPath)
    {
        ReportViewer ReportViewer1 = new ReportViewer();
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new 
CustomReportCredentials("MyUsername", "MyPassword", "MyDomain");
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = 
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(ReportServer);
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = ReportPath;

       
        byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Render("PDF");

        return bytes;
    }

    public class CustomReportCredentials : 
    Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials
    {
        // local variable for network credential.    
        private string _UserName;
        private string _PassWord;
        private string _DomainName;
        public CustomReportCredentials(string UserName, string PassWord, 
string DomainName)
        {
            _UserName = UserName;
            _PassWord = PassWord;
            _DomainName = DomainName;
        }

        public System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity ImpersonationUser
        {
            get
            {
                return null;  // not use ImpersonationUser        
            }
        }

        public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
        {
            get
            {
                // use NetworkCredentials            
                return new NetworkCredential(_UserName, _PassWord, 
_DomainName);
            }
        }

        public bool GetFormsCredentials(out Cookie authCookie, out string 
user, out string password, out string authority)
        {
            authCookie = null;
            user = password = authority = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. In which library can I find the `CustomReportCredentials` class?

Comment: Sorry, I've just added it to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. It seems to work. But is there a way to download the file in an asynchronous way? Building up our report takes about a minute or so, so it would block that server thread for a long time.