# SSRS Reports are not downloading

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Dear team I am getting this error while downloading the Reports.
Checked in server local system it was working fine but after hosting the above error is comming.

`System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 503: Server Error. at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods() at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SetConnectionSSLForMethod(String methodname) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1 retryMethod) at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession() at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Utilities.SSRSReportDownloaderAT(String rdlfile, Dictionary`2 dparams, String FileFormat, String FileName, String userid) at Online_Registration.Views.AdmitcardDwonload.btndownload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: POTENTIAL ANSWER: Notice the error starts in the stacktrace at the call `SetParameters` and see in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63515808/495455 how "GetParameters" is the place I put a Try/Catch to use different credentials. I think you should try a similar thing in your btndownload_Click to test if SetParameters works - otherwise switch credentials and then try if SetParameters works.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.. Working fine and issue resolved

Comment: You're welcome, upvote the answer I linked to when you have enough points. Good luck!